# Installing MCC-LIDAR on Mac

Tags: installation, lidar, mac, compile

I'm trying to install `mcc-lidar` on Mac but get into problems when compiling.

```
[  3%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/mcc-lidar.dir/LasDataFormat.cpp.o
/Users/Oskar/Documents/mcclidar-code/src/LasDataFormat.cpp:59:29: error: no
      member named 'str' in namespace 'boost'
        std::string scale = boost::str(boost::format("%d") % scaleDoma...
                            ~~~~~~~^
/Users/Oskar/Documents/mcclidar-code/src/LasDataFormat.cpp:59:40: error: no
      member named 'format' in namespace 'boost'
        std::string scale = boost::str(boost::format("%d") % scaleDoma...
                                       ~~~~~~~^
/Users/Oskar/Documents/mcclidar-code/src/LasDataFormat.cpp:60:33: error: no
      member named 'str' in namespace 'boost'
        std::string threshold = boost::str(boost::format("%d") % curva...
                                ~~~~~~~^
/Users/Oskar/Documents/mcclidar-code/src/LasDataFormat.cpp:60:44: error: no
      member named 'format' in namespace 'boost'
        std::string threshold = boost::str(boost::format("%d") % curva...
                                           ~~~~~~~^
4 errors generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/mcc-lidar.dir/LasDataFormat.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/mcc-lidar.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Does anyone know why I get this problem? Has anyone at all managed to compile and run this app on Mac?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On [this page](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcclidar/mailman/message/33643315/) I found the solution. I had to add `#include <boost/format.hpp>` to `LasDataFormat.cpp`